# Converting from FLV to MP4 using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, h.264, flv

I have a library of several thousand flv files which I need to convert to mp4. I'm trying to use ffmpeg to do so but I'm running into some issues.

Primarily:

1) I can't switch from FLV to MP4 without re-encoding. If I do I get a message from ffmpeg saying "Could not find tag for codec flv1 in stream #0, codec not currently supported in container"

2) If I re-encode the videos, the resultant videos are lower quality (I see artifacting in VLC) AND larger. For example one video went from 2.5MB to 4.3MB (almost double in size)

Given number two you may be asking yourself - why convert then?

The answer is I need to stream these to mobile devices (phones/tablets etc) and flv isn't supported. So I need to convert the files but I can't tolerate more than a minimum change in quality, and preferably zero to no increase in size.

Here's the ffmpeg command I'm running:

```
ffmpeg -i $_.FullName -movflags faststart -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 "$($_.BaseName).mp4"
```

(Note that I'm running ffmpeg from powershell so:

```
$_.FullName = the original file name 
"$($_.BaseName).mp4" = the original file name with mp4 extension)
```

Can any FFMPEG guru's help me to understand what I'm doing wrong? Is there some set of parameters I can use to make this conversion result in less loss of quality and similar size?

Note I've also tried "-c:v libx264 -preset veryslow -crf 23 -c:a copy". Using present "veryslow" doesn't result in any appreciable difference.

***UPDATE***
I'm using the following options:

```
ffmpeg -i $_.FullName -c:v libx264 -preset veryslow -crf 19 -c:a copy "$($_.BaseName).mp4"
```

Here's the full output:

```
    ffmpeg version 2.8.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
      built with gcc 5.2.0 (GCC)
      configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfi
    g --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --
    enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libm
    p3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --en
    able-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --ena
    ble-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enabl
    e-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
      libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
      libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
      libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
      libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
      libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
      libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
      libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
      libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
    Input #0, flv, from 'C:\Users\brad\Desktop\ffmpeg\Originals\1019800-1278575542468.flv':
      Metadata:
        canSeekToEnd    : false
        createdby       : FMS 3.5
        creationdate    : Thu Jul 08 03:52:25 2010
      Duration: 00:00:56.94, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 360 kb/s
        Stream #0:0: Video: flv1, yuv420p, 320x240, 1k tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
        [libx264 @ 02cf7300] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2
        [libx264 @ 02cf7300] profile High, level 4.2
        [libx264 @ 02cf7300] 264 - core 148 r2638 7599210 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2015 - http://www.videolan.or
    g/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=16 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x133 me=umh subme=10 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1
     me_range=24 chroma_me=1 trellis=2 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=7 lookahead_th
    reads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=8 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=
    2 b_bias=0 direct=3 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=60
    rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=19.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
    Output #0, mp4, to '1019800-1278575542468.mp4':
      Metadata:
        canSeekToEnd    : false
        createdby       : FMS 3.5
        creationdate    : Thu Jul 08 03:52:25 2010
        encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
        Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 320x240, q=-1--1, 1k fps, 16k tbn, 1k tbc
        Metadata:
          encoder         : Lavc56.60.100 libx264
    Stream mapping:
      Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (flv1 (flv) -> h264 (libx264))
    Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
    frame=57117 fps=199 q=-1.0 Lsize=    5611kB time=00:00:57.11 bitrate= 804.8kbits/s dup=56685 drop=0
    video:5184kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 8.229259%
    [libx264 @ 02cf7300] frame I:230   Avg QP:15.92  size:  8828
    [libx264 @ 02cf7300] frame P:6399  Avg QP:17.19  size:   385
    [libx264 @ 02cf7300] frame B:50488 Avg QP:27.13  size:    16
    [libx264 @ 02cf7300] consecutive B-frames:  0.4%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  2.3%  0.0%  0.0% 97.2%
    [libx264 @ 02cf7300] mb I  I16..4:  2.9% 92.6%  4.5%
    [libx264 @ 02cf7300] mb P  I16..4:  0.1%  2.0%  0.2%  P16..4:  2.4%  1.2%  1.1%  0.1%  0.0%    skip:92.9%
    [libx264 @ 02cf7300] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8:  2.6%  0.0%  0.0%  direct: 0.0%  skip:97.3%  L0:45.0% L1:5
4.9% BI: 0.0%
    [libx264 @ 02cf7300] 8x8 transform intra:90.7% inter:76.5%
    [libx264 @ 02cf7300] direct mvs  spatial:75.2% temporal:24.8%
    [libx264 @ 02cf7300] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 94.4% 96.8% 64.8% inter: 0.3% 0.4% 0.1%
    [libx264 @ 02cf7300] i16 v,h,dc,p: 16% 25% 18% 41%
    [libx264 @ 02cf7300] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 19% 28% 30%  4%  3%  3%  4%  4%  5%
    [libx264 @ 02cf7300] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 18% 22%  9% 11%  8%  7% 10%  8%  7%
    [libx264 @ 02cf7300] i8c dc,h,v,p: 30% 34% 23% 13%
    [libx264 @ 02cf7300] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.1% UV:0.1%
    [libx264 @ 02cf7300] ref P L0: 74.1% 19.7%  4.5%  0.6%  0.1%  0.2%  0.0%  0.1%  0.0%  0.1%  0.0%  0.2%  0.0%  0.2%  0.0%
  0.1%
    [libx264 @ 02cf7300] ref B L0: 95.5%  1.6%  0.7%  0.5%  0.4%  0.3%  0.3%  0.2%  0.1%  0.1%  0.1%  0.1%  0.1%  0.0%  0.0%

    [libx264 @ 02cf7300] ref B L1: 84.5% 15.5%
    [libx264 @ 02cf7300] kb/s:743.46
```

```
Original Video Size: 2.44 MB
New Video Size: 5.6 MB
```

Comment: Try with a lower CRF value. In any case, show the full console output of one of the conversions.

Comment: Take one of the problem videos, what is the video codec and audio codec used? Filesize changes might be because the mystery codec used inside FLV. For better quality images try adjusting output bit-rate (like for 720p use 3000kb - 5000kb). MP4 will only contain AAC or MP3 audio codec so be sure the FLV also contains one of those codecs when using ` -c:a copy`. Otherwise re-encode with something like `-c:a libfaac` (or was it **libfdk_aac** can't remember the exact AAC encoder name so search it).

Comment: Video Codec = FLV1, Audio Codec = NellyMoser ASAO (Nell)

Comment: Have you tried what Mulvya said?

Comment: Tried running with -crf 19 and pasted output above. That seems to have improved the artifacting but as mentioned at the bottom of the post the size is still double which isn't ideal... is there some way to keep the quality acceptable but also keep the size at least very similar if not the same or better?

Comment: Regarding update... Don't use `-c:a copy` since NellyMoser is not a valid MP4 codec. If you leave any audio specifics then FFmpeg will encode working AAC data for you. Also FLV1 is Sorenson Spark codec so yes you have to re-encode to H264 otherwise `c:v copy` would have worked if the FLV already contained MPEG's own a/v codecs. As for size well it can't be helped cos the transcoding (& quality settings) affect final file size. Experiment with CRF and video's bitrate (eg: `-b:v 3000k`) for an acceptable size.

Comment: I've written extensively on the `flv` > `mp4` topic at [Converting FLV to MP4 With FFmpeg The Ultimate Guide](https://addpipe.com/blog/flv-to-mp4/)